# PrimeFaces with multiple p:fileUpload tags on one page -- only the last tag works

Tags: file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces

I use PrimeFaces 3.0-SNAPSHOT with JBoss AS7. I put three `<p:fileUpload>` tags in one form with option `auto=true`.

The problem is that to upload files I have to start with the last form and then upload to prelast and finally to the first one. Otherwise nothing is sent to the server (there is nothing to watch in FireBug JS console nor in Net console). Do you know how to resolve it? Uploading multiple files using one component is not usable for me.

EDIT: Forms are like:

```
<p:fileUpload id="videoThumbnail" 
    fileUploadListener="#{videoWrapper.handleImageUpload}"
    update="#{@form}" process="#{@all}" auto="true" showButtons="false"/>
```

And `videoWrapper.handleImageUpload` is a typical PrimeFaces uploading handler. I don't enclose it, because I think it's not a problem. Requests are not sent to the server, so java server side seems to be unrelated.

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588687/pfileupload-does-not-set-uploaded-file-in-backing-bean and post your xhtml/java code

Comment: thanks for comment, but my problems seem to be a client-side one: POST is not sent to server, so I can't check it there

Comment: Please post more code from you .xhtml page, at least the whole `<h:form>` tags as well as the bean code. That would give us more info about what you're doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got an answer on PrimeFaces forum: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=16917&p=52525. Now this situation is not supported, maybe it will change in the future.